# Important english word which doesn't exist in another language

Tags: cross-linguistic, lexicography

I'm looking for an important English word which doesn't have a corresponding word in another language. I would be happy even it's a language spoken only by a small population.

Preferably, the word is not a colour. Please provide a reference if possible.

Comment: I'm sure there are plenty of examples, but just to give one, someone writing a dissertation in Welsh, would have to call their dissertation "treithawd hir" (lit. 'long essay'). But just because there's no one-to-one correspondence between words, doesn't mean that Welsh can't express the concept of _dissertation_, as I've demonstrated.

Comment: also, you might want to define "important", which might not be easy/possible.

Comment: "important" means "within the 1000 words most used in English" according to a random list of frequencies. Thank you for your example, but I would prefer a more "shocking". Like : "water" doesn't exist in this language... (even it's a very very little known language !)

Comment: yes, I guess you could use a Swadesh list or something. Maybe there's a database somewhere, I always thought a Swadesh list database would be very useful...

Comment: I've found Swadesh lists on Wikipedia, but I'm afraid by the fact that there are a lot of words which have no equivalent : we don't know if the language has really no equivalent, or just no strict equivalent. It would be better if I could find an example given in the literature.

Comment: Why 'shocking'? What is the intent of such a search? Do you just want one example or do you want more (if so, why), to maybe find a pattern?

Comment: This question is somewhat fundamentally flawed as if a word is important enough to be one of the top 1000 used words in a languages then it is either A) a grammatical device (like "and", a conjunction, "to", a preposition, "a", an article, or even the "fewest" example given below) that is unlikely to be needed in another language, or the word represents a very common (and thus likely universal) concept like "people", "man", "water", "food", etc.

Comment: Another problem as that the research into the [Saphir-Whorf Hypothesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_relativity) has shown us that just because a language doesn't have a word for a specific concept doesn't mean the speakers are incapable of conceiving of it. They tend to simply create a word/combination of words to address that concept or adopt a foreign loanword. Addressing the "fewest" example below, even if Swedish doesn't have a *single word equivalent* to "fewest", they do have their own way of expressing that concept.

Comment: 1000 was an example, 10 000 if you want. But maybe you're right, and this task is impossible.

Comment: In my experience few languages have words for both "shade" and "shadow". German tourists are forever wanting to find a shadow from the sun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't exact because you didn't describe whether the word should have exact equivalent or it's enough to have a rather synonym in another language but with essential semantic difference.

My favorite example is couple of English words "issue" and "problem" and their translation to Russian. The technical support team at my work is especially trained to use "issue" for any thing which is treated by customer as something which needs explanation or fixing; but it's very hard to translate "issue" to Russian because all translations have a main sense more closer to some another English word; e.g. "вопрос" is "question", "тема" is "topic", "предмет" is "subject" or "thing" or even "agenda", and so on. Similar discussions in Russian tends to use "проблема", but it's much softer than English "problem"; the latter generally means a kind of principal discrepancy, which solving needs even some sacrifice, while Russian "проблема" is closer to "issue" in its level but not in kind ("issue" can be a feature request or even a polite suggestion). So, it's impossible to give a one-to-one translation for English "issue" or "problem" to Russian; each translation variant needs detection of importance level and selecting a proper equivalent among more than ten similar words. Whether is it similar to colors for you, I don't know, but anyway this isn't for colors.

Answer (score 2):

If you really do mean a common/important word in English without a reasonably-close, single-word translation in at least one other language, there must be many, many examples.

My favorite example is that the word "fewest" is missing in Swedish. Swedish has close equivalents for few and fewer but switches to "minst antal" (roughly "least number") for fewest (though some may mistranslate to the Swedish word for "smallest").

Of course, you might discount "fewest" since only "few" is common enough to qualify as important. A database search should provide better hits.

Comment: Thank you. I'm, though, not totally satisfied because this isn't very shocking and because there is no reference. But thank you !

Comment: No, not shocking but loads of fun to reveal to Swedes. Haven't met one yet who had realized this, despite being highly proficient in English. A proper response is to point out that the Swedish word "lagom" has no equivalent in English -- that's debatable but too far off-topic here anyway.

Comment: Completely the same in Russian. "Fewest" translates to "меньше всего" "menshe vsego".

Answer (score 2):

Articles would be an easy and probably quite shocking (given their frequency in English) case. As far as I recall, there is no equivalent for “the” in Latin, nor do I recall one in Japanese.

Comment: The difference between the indefinite, definite, and null articles in English are handled by completely different means in topic-comment languages such as Japanese. Alternatively you could always analyse Japanese as translating them all to the one article in Japanese, the null article (-;

Answer (score 1):

What could really be hardly translated into Russian is 'privacy' (although some might disagree stating that it is translated as *покой*).

What is really remarkable is the reported absence of [numerals](http://www2b.abc.net.au/science/k2/stn/archives/archive32/newposts/149/topic149004.shtm) and/or [generic terms for 'fish' or 'tree'](http://books.google.ru/books?id=2pGdpr-1bA8C&pg=PA160&lpg=PA160&dq=no%20word%20for%20tree%20in%20Australian%20language&source=bl&ots=AiBn9HAX0F&sig=l8z5v5QYKwUAuX77rNXil05eofU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6niUUaHMM7CQ4ASM1IDQCA&ved=0CFAQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=no%20word%20for%20tree%20in%20Australian%20language&f=false) in some Australian languages.

Comment: Those sources are not trustworthy.

Comment: Neither is your remark.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from French: "si", which means "I disagree with your negative statement/question." For example:

Tu parles pas anglais? = You don't speak English?

Mais si. = Your statement/question is incorrect. I do speak English.

Comment: Largely related: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/28582/26446

Comment: Bah I just translate such things as "yes I do" or "yes you're right". I think it's like claiming that English doesn't one or other of the Portuguese/Spanish verbs "ser" and "estar". It does but both just translate to "to be". The same imperfect alignment exists to a varying degree for any two words in any two languages.

Answer (score 0):

The Western Desert Language in Australia does not have a word directly equivalent to English 'love'. Of course, this very important concept can still be easily expressed. One way of doing this is with a construction that combines the serial form of the verb *puntuni* 'make large/loud' with the verb *yuntjurringanyi* 'like/want' (to improve clarity free pronouns are used rather than the more typical clitics):

```
  Ngayulu nyuntu   -nya puntu        -ra  yuntju      -rri    -nganyi    
  1sg.NOM 2sg      -ACC make.large   -SER like/want   -INCH   -PRES
  "I love you."
```

NOM = nominative
ACC = accusative
SER = serial
INCH = inchoative
PRES = present

Answer (score -1):

In addition to the answer by Netch I would give some other examples of words whose equivalent does not exist in Russian:

- item
- entry

Comment: Any chance you could provide more detail about how Russian expresses these concepts and it how they differ from the English?

Comment: Actually, there are: item = штука/предмет/экземпляр; entry = ввод + specifying word in genitive (for computer science) or выход (as opposite to 'exit').